# Ng-map - infowindow on markers sometimes not appearing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

I'm using the ng-map directive to display a map. The map has markers that show an infowindow whenever there's a mouseover on the marker. Sometimes however, the infowindow doesn't appear.

Other than this, I haven't been able to identify any pattern to what's happening, as the problem occurs for a different marker each time. I'm outputting data to the infowindow however the issue doesn't seem to be 'data related' as all data for the selected location seems to be correct at the point where the issue occurs.

I have a showInfo method that is being called on a mouseover like this:

```
showInfo(event, loc, infoWindowTemplate, map, mapsController) {
```

- loc - data for the clicked location
- infoWindowTemplate - the info window template to use (this is always the same for a particular map, however this is configurable, so if I'm showing a map for mobile, I use one infowindow template, if I'm showing a desktop map, I use a different one)
- map - a reference to the NgMap object on the controller
- mapsController - the controller itself (I strongly suspect that this is a bad code smell - it was the easiest way I could figure out to get reference back to the controller following the mouseover)

Here is the body of the method:

```
        map.getMap(mapsController.mapId).then(function (myMap) {

            var selectedMarker = myMap.markers["L: " + loc.position[0] + ", " + loc.position[1]];
            selectedMarker.locationInfo = loc;

            console.log("about to show infowindow - infoWindowTemplate = " + infoWindowTemplate);
            // console output = "cached-myTemplate.html"

            myMap.showInfoWindow(infoWindowTemplate, selectedMarker);
```

selectedMarker is definitely referring to the correct marker object. My template looks like this:

```
<script id="cached-myTemplate.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <a class="map-location__link" href="/locations/{{anchor.locationInfo.locationId}}" target="_blank">
                <img src="{{anchor.locationInfo.locationImageThumbnail}}" />
        </a>
</script>
```

The issue seems to be that calling 'showInfoWindow' is intermittently failing somehow (although there are no errors in the console). Any comments or answers with ideas of what may be causing the issue or what else I can do to diagnose it will be appreciated!

Comment: same issue i'm facing. have you get any solution of this ?

Comment: Just figured this out - see my answer

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that this is a timing issue. Delaying the 'turn' in which showInfoWindow is called (by adding a short timeout) fixed the issue:

```
map.getMap(mapsController.mapId).then(function (myMap) {

            ....

            this.$timeout(function () {
                dealmap.showInfoWindow(infoWindowTemplate, selectedMarker);
            }, 100)

}.bind(this));
```